# Python Text to Speech - While True say something

Tags: python

So i'm trying to make a program say something while a variable is True using python's pyttsx library but it isn't working.

When the program starts it says what I want it to say, but after it completes the first sentence it just repeats the first syllable, and I don't understand why. The code is:

```
import pyttsx

text_to_speech_engine = pyttsx.init()

while True:

    text_to_speech_engine.say('Sample Text')
    text_to_speech_engine.runAndWait()
```